# Karpenter autoscaling eks

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, autoscaling, karpenter

How to ensure Karpenter spin up instances equally in all availability zones?

Used the below code, but it will not spin up pods in all availability zone's at the same time.Rather it picks random availability zone for provisioning new nodes.

```
- key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
      operator: In
      values: ["us-east-2a", "us-east-2b", "us-east-2c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [Pod topology spread constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/) in your pod spec.

The three supported [topologyKey values that Karpenter supports](https://karpenter.sh/docs/concepts/scheduling/#topology-spread) are:

```
topology.kubernetes.io/zone
kubernetes.io/hostname
karpenter.sh/capacity-type
```

Thanks,
Manish